# docker run <image> : /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe : No such file or directory

Tags: docker

I am trying to run my image, but I get the error described in the title, it seems to not be able to locate a file / directory. I have googled around and found various fixes, but nothing worked for me.

In the container logs I found /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe : No such file or directory, so it seems to have some issue there.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3

# Set the working directory to /app
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs

ENV APP_HOME /fitnesspage

RUN mkdir $APP_HOME

ADD . $APP_HOME

WORKDIR $APP_HOME

ADD Gemfile* $APP_HOME/

RUN bundle install

RUN chmod 0777 -R $APP_HOME

RUN useradd -m myuser
USER myuser

CMD bin/rails server
```

My bin/rails:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

I think from what I am reading that it struggles with the CMD in the Dockerfile, but I don't know how to proceed to fix it. I have tried to change #!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe to #!/usr/bin/env ruby in bin/bundle, bin/rails and bin/rake. Made no difference except for the error.

EDIT:
The error changed to /usr/bin/env: ruby : No such file or directory instead.

Comment: /usr/bin/env: ruby : No such file or directory

Comment: "Made no difference except for the error". What did the error change to? Ah. OK now I understand.

Comment: I would put an echo PATH before and see if it contains ruby. If not, make it contain it. And probably drop the .exe part.

Comment: I'm sorry, put the echo PATH where?

Comment: In the docker file, just before you call your commands that fail. RUN echo $PATH. Should print to your console the contents of the path. Ruby should be in there.

Comment: Try `CMD ruby bin/rails server`

Comment: @Robert that solved it! I've been stuck on this for quite a while now. You should probably add it as an answer or I will self-answer incase others are stuck on it like I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CMD ruby bin/rails server
```

It seems that /usr/bin/env is not able to find Ruby. But as you use the official ruby base image, the `ruby` command is available.